# How to get filter options on category page using REST APIs Magento 2

Tags: magento2, category, filter, rest-api

I need to get all applicable filters on a category page. I am using below API to fetch all filters.

```
http://localhost/magento/rest/default/V1/products/attributes?searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][value]=1&searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][field]=is_filterable
```

It will give all filterable attributes of product. How can I pass category reference in this API so that it will return only filterable attribute which applicable for that category only.

Comment: I am looking for same filter options on category page REST API have you get any solutions?

Comment: Unfortunately no, :(